# Hash function implementation in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog, and I want to know can we implement this in Prolog:

```
a = hash(first).
```

And, one who knows `first` can calculate `a`, but one who knows `a` can't calculate `first`.

Comment: What exactly do you want? What `hash/1` is supposed to do?

Comment: These are actually two unrelated questions: (1) how to implement a unidirectional hashing function, and (2) how to do it in Prolog.  If you'll post your answer to (1), people will be able to answer (2).

Comment: @All: Actually hash is a function which I want to implement in prolog. The property of hash function is that it is oneway computable. For eg. Plus(X,Y,Z) gives the sum of X and Y in Z and if you know Z and any one of X and Y, you can calculate other. Similarly In Hash function we provide a single input and it will generate output like a = hash(input). Now using input one can generate output a but using a he can't generate input. the input and a both are then numbers. Hope I am able to explain and if still some query is there I can explain in more better way.

Comment: The Prolog way of doing things, generally speaking, is to write a predicate **hash/2** such that the call to hash(First,A) with First given as a "ground" term (integer?) succeeds by binding A to what you were denoting `a = hash(first)`.

Comment: @hardmath: I was also thinking for the same but we have to provide one more functionality that by knowing First one can derive A. I was unable to visualize this thing.

Comment: @user616141:  Certainly the predicate **hash/2** can be written in such a way that for a specified value of First, `hash(First,A)` succeeds by binding the "trapdoor" value to A, but calls to `hash(First,A)` with an unbound value of First always fail.  One thinks immediately of a public key encryption scheme, where First is the "plaintext" integer and A is the encrypted version.  Breaking the encryption would take such a long time that the immediate use of an "inverse" function is not feasible.  BTW some Prologs and Prolog like languages allow for the syntax to be that of a unary function.

Comment: @hardmath: You must mean crypto hashing, not public key systems.

Comment: @larsmans: I'm trying to distinguish a mere syntactic approach to preventing a user from asking for an inverse value (the function is one-way in syntax) from the more substantive implementation of a trapdoor function.  Not sure which Anil Mundra (note updated user name) wants, but the public key encryption scheme implements a 1-1 trapdoor function.  That's usually overkill for a hashing function (allowing for collisions).

Comment: @hardmath: I was wondering to implement that one-way in syntax. I think if we implement using "trapdoor" logic then it will not work for other values and we have to bind all the values, that may be not acceptable. In the case of one-way syntax I don't think that collusions will be there.

Answer (score 1):

Typicall a hash function is not injective in general. Means
that for any value a there is most often a first1 and a first2
such that:

```
a = hash(first1)
a = hash(first2)
```

So one cannot say for sure what was the argument to the
hash function. But since a hash is supposed to be a small 
value that can be easily used in search etc., it typically
gives some information about the domain of arguments.

If you want a hash where it is difficult to make backward
deductions to the argument, you should use a digest.
Digest is typically a value generated by some cryptographic 
algorithm and it is practically infeasible to make 
deductions about the argument.

I guess the predicates term_hash/2 or so usually found in 
Prolog systems qualify as hash and not as digest. But
you can also implement your own hash function easily. Something
along the lines:

```
my_hash(X,N) :- atom(X), !, atom_codes(X,L), my_hash_codes(L,N).
my_hash(X,N) :- X=..[F|L], my_hash(F,M), my_hash_args(L,R), my_hash_codes([M|R],N).

my_hash_codes([],0).
my_hash_codes([X|Y],N) :- my_hash_codes(Y,M), N is (X+M*31) mod 65531.

my_hash_args([],[]).
my_hash_args([X|Y],[M|N]) :- my_hash(X,M), my_hash_args(Y,N).
```

The helper predicate my_hash_codes/2 sends a list of numbers to a new
number. The helper predicate my_hash_args/2 computes the hash of each
list element and builds a new list. The predicate my_hash works for
atoms and compounds, but it could be also extended to numbers.

Bye